# How to optimize this filtering in javascript?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have a big object (called "container" in the following code) from a json file. This object contains many elements (about 20 000), each of it being an object with a "rank" property. It is too big to print it here, but here is an object with a same structure:

```
{
    guy1: {rank:0, infos:"the first guy ever"},
    guy0: {rank:2, infos:"another guy"},
    something: {rank:1, infos:"something else"}
}
```

First I wanted to put the 10 of them with the smallest rank in a list (after I slightly modified them with a function I call here *modify*), so I did:

```
var res = [];
for (var key in container) {
    if (container.hasOwnProperty(key) && container[key]["rank"]<10) {
        res.push(modify(container[key]));
    }
}
```

But now I want to *do_something* with the 10 of them with the smallest rank but only among those who pass *my_test*. I could do:

```
var res = [];
var filt_cont = Array.from(container).filter(my_test);//actually this doesn't work. I currently use a long non-efficient way to do that but i guess I can find something better on my own)
for (var key in filt_cont) {
    if (filt_cont.hasOwnProperty(key) && filt_cont[key]["rank"]<10) {
        res.push(modify(filt_cont[key]));
    }
}
```

but as I want my code to be the fastest possible I would like to know if there is a faster way to do that. Also I want to keep the 10 best (with the smallest rank) among those who pass the test, and this only gives those who both were in the first 10 before the filter and pass the filter.

It that's relevant, *my_test* is four comparisons and two attributes readings and *modify* is 6 attribute readings and 2 int additions.

Comment: *object contains many elements (about 20 000)*, hm, is it an array? or just for this usage the false data structure?

Comment: No, it's an object interpreted from a json dictionnary (non-sorted), I will add a small example of what it looks like, it will be clearer.

Comment: Drop the `container.hasOwnProperty(key) &&`. It's unnecessary and takes some time.

Comment: If you are often querying your container by rank, you really should use an array where the items are sorted by rank insted of an object. Then it's trivial to write a fast function that gets the 10 first items. Don't micro-optimise your code, optimise your data structures and algorithms.

Comment: Do you think it would be more efficient this way? I guess it could work. Checking that tomorrow.

Comment: It works great! I was scared at the beginning that building this array would take long (I saw it as a quadratic operation), but actually it goes linearly.

Comment: @AnneAunyme, you could anwer you own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I go with this:

```
var filt_cont = []
for (var key in container) {
    filt_cont[container[key]["rank"]] = container[key]
}
filt_cont = filt_cont.filter(my_test)
return filt_cont[0:9]
```

Works fast enough, apparently creating a list like this, adding items by their index, is not too expensive.

I note that if *undefined* would pass *my_test* that could be a problem, but as that's not the case it's alright.